# Calculate the distance between all arrays inside an Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, distance

I have an Arraylist that contains int[] arrays and I want to find the min distance between all the arrays.

> [ [2,3,5] , [3,4], [6,2,8] .... ]

I know it needs nested loops but as I struggle with this I can see it is not trivial! Here is my code:

The all_occurance Arraylist gets filled all the arrays:

```
ArrayList<int[]> all_occurances = new ArrayList<int[]>(); 

for (int i=0; i<=ips.length-1; i++)
    all_occurances.add(((BlockPosting) ips[i]).getPositions());
```

When I try to calculate the min distance of course it doesn't work:

```
int minDiff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;        
int diff=0;

for (int i=0; i<=all_occurances.size()-1;i++){
    for (int j=0; j<=all_occurances.get(i).length;j++){

        int[] a = all_occurances.get(i);
        int[] b = all_occurances.get(j);
        diff = a[i] - b[j];
    }
    minDiff = Math.min( diff, minDiff );
}
```

Am I in the right track here??? I cant figure out how to iterate through all arrays inside the arraylist without getting an out of bounds exception, and I guess I have to handle different sizes of arrays as well ... any suggestions more than welcome... thanks

Comment: I never understand why people mix ArrayLists with Arrays of primitives, why not use an ArrayList of an ArrayList?

Comment: @Wombat the getPositions method returns an Array

Comment: You need to start by defining what the "distance" means. Your problem is here `diff = a[i] - b[j];` You are looking at the arrays using indexes that have no meaning for those arrays

Answer (score 1):

This for-loop is causing an issue:

```
for (int j=0; j<=all_occurances.get(i).length;j++){
```

This iterates `j` to the size of each of the arrays in the arraylist, so you will get an outOfBoundsException. To fix this, either subtract `all_occurances.get(i).length` by 1, or get rid of the equals sign and use only a less-than operator like so:

```
for (int j=0; j< all_occurances.get(i).length;j++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
for (int j=0; j<=all_occurances.get(i).length;j++)
```

to

```
for (int j=0; j<=all_occurances.get(i).length-1;j++)
```

should avoid out of bound exception.

And also noticed, you iterate using `i` over the size of `Arraylist` in the outer loop and while you're using `a[i]` within the inner loop to access an element of an array inside that list. This would also throw the same exception for the cases when you `Arraylist` elements are more than the elements of a single array `int[]` within it.

So, ideally would suggest you to precisely define `diff` and `minDiff` and to use `Arraylist<Arraylist<Integer>>`  as the datatype.

Comment: while this is true, it does not answer the question

Comment: I prefer `for (int j=0; j < all_occurances.get(i).length;j++)`

Comment: @ScaryWombat even I would, just used the convention that the OP was using.